# how to make x,y axis appear in an axes in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a text file (which I extracted during run using np.savetxt function) _anchors.out

```
-84 -40 99 55
-176 -88 191 103
-360 -184 375 199
-56 -56 71 71
-120 -120 135 135
-248 -248 263 263
-36 -80 51 95
-80 -168 95 183
-168 -344 183 359
```

These are 9 boxes centered around point 7.5. I can see the boxes using code below(qq.py)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

b = np.loadtxt('_anchors.out','int')
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.set_xbound(-400,400)
ax1.set_ybound(-400,400)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in b:
    ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((x1,y1), x2-x1, y2-y1,fill=False))
fig1.show()
```

and the figure is [image: graph with no axis]
But I want to see the X, and Y axis together(not the 'axes' in matplotlib term). I've searched some solution but it's not clear to me. How should I modify above code? (you can check it using ipython. run ipython, and inside type 'run qq.py')

What I want to see is below(X and Y axes added)[image: here]

Comment: What do you call X and Y axis if they are not the matplotlib axes?

Comment: ^^ I don't know. I see 'xaxis' and 'yaxis'. may I should do something with them.

Comment: Show what image you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you want `plt.xlabel('data')`?

Comment: I added pictures. please suggest how I can fix the code.(I'm doing this to better understand a code)

Comment: @JulienBernu, in matplotlib, we have figures and inside we can have many axes(I don't know why they call it axes, it's just subplots of a figure). Do you know what they call the real axes (as in math) in matplot lib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html) you can achieve this with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

b = np.loadtxt('_anchors.out','int')
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.set_xbound(-400,400)
ax1.set_ybound(-400,400)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in b:
    ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((x1,y1), x2-x1, y2-y1,fill=False))

#Change spine position
ax1.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax1.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax1.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

#Show figure
fig1.show()
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: oh, that was it. Thanks. I later tried  using ax1.arrow function to add horizontal and vertical arrows like below, ax1.arrow(-400,0,800,0)
ax1.arrow(0,-400,0,800) but your answer seems better.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

b = np.loadtxt('./_anchors.out','int')
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.set_xbound(-400,400)
ax1.set_ybound(-400,400)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in b:
    ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((x1,y1), x2-x1, y2-y1,fill=False))

# Move left y-axis and bottom x-axis to center of the figure
ax1.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax1.spines['left'].set_color('r')
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color('r')
# Show ticks in the left and lower axes only
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(bottom='on', top='off', direction='inout', color='r')
ax1.yaxis.set_tick_params(left='on', right='off', direction='inout', color='r')    

# Remove upper and right axes
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Actually you may set tick labels as you want.

Comment: thanks for the tick_param setting and color setting info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this alternative that plots dashed lines:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

b = np.loadtxt('_anchors.out','int')
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.set_xbound(-400,400)
ax1.set_ybound(-400,400)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in b:
    ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((x1,y1), x2-x1, y2-y1,fill=False))
plt.plot((0, 0), (-400, 400), 'r--')
plt.plot((-400, 400), (0, 0), 'r--')
fig1.show()
```

Which outputs:
[image]

Comment: Also [```axvline```](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline) and [```axhline```](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline).

Comment: Or for ```pyplot``` - http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline , http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline